# Abs. Positioning difference in Chrome vs Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, position

I have a flyout menu, and the menu is positioned `top: 100%;`. In Firefox it sits flush against its `parent div`, but in chrome it overlaps the `parent div` by a pixel or two.

The css for the menu is:

```
div.menu { 
    z-index: 100; 
    width: 600px; 
    margin-top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%; left: 0; 
    padding: 0 0 6px 0; 
    color: black;
    background: #fff660; 
}
```

**Chrome version: 42.0.2311.152 dev-m Firefox version: 39.0**

I thought by 2015 that modern browsers would be standards compliant and quirk free, but apparently no. Do I need to use browser specific code for these browsers? Anyone able to spot it?

Comment: Does the parent, by any chance, have a bottom border? - Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: And to answer your last remark: yes, but only if you tell them to. Do you have a doctype declaration?

Comment: Ah, doctype, got lazy about that, am using doctype transitional, so i guess it should be strict, unless something else has come along? No bottom border. I got into this during ie's infamous standards noncompliance, and so have become paranoid about using strict.

Comment: Modern IE versions are much more standards compliant. So that would be OK. Also, ehm, "something else", you mean since HTML 4.01 strict? Yes. Yes, something else has come along.

Comment: What do you think of doctypes vs browser specific code?